# Android Calendar integration in Android OS 4

Tags: android, calendar

I use the undocumented API's for adding calendar event for Android OS 2.2. Now Android OS 4 is out, naturally the API's I used don't work! I looked at the Android SDK regarding the calendar api's in level 14 but I'd not able to found a clue how to use this in my project that I have created using Android OS 2.2. Because when I use `CalendarContract` class in my project it shows error. So I am not able to find the clue what to do and how to used this class in my project that I have created using Android OS 2.2.

If anyone has any samples to share or a link to samples, please let me know.

**Calendar Api Class**

```
public abstract class CalendarAPI 
{
private static CalendarAPI api;

public static CalendarAPI getAPI() 
{
    String apiClass;
    if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) > Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
        apiClass = "com.example.calendar.CycleManagerSDK8 ";
    } else {
        apiClass = "com.example.calendar.CycleManagerSDK14 ";
    }

    try 
    {
        Class<? extends CalendarAPI> realClass = Class.forName(apiClass).asSubclass(CalendarAPI.class);
        api = realClass.newInstance();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }

    return api;
}

public abstract boolean setAlertOnDevice(Context c) ;
}
```

**class for SDKVersion 8 - 13**

```
public class CycleManagerSDK8 extends CalendarAPI
{
public boolean setAlertOnDevice(Context c)
{                   
    Resources res = c.getResources();

    Uri EVENTS_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/" + "events");

    Uri REMINDERS_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/" + "reminders");

        ContentResolver cr = c.getContentResolver();

    Date dtStartDate = getStartDate();  

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    cal.setTime(dtStartDate);
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, m_iStart);

    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);  
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, DEFAULT_TIME_OF_DATE);     
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, DEFAULT_TIME_OF_DATE); 
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, DEFAULT_TIME_OF_DATE);

    String str = m_reminderText + res.getString(R.string.alert_start);                                          
    m_strDescription = res.getString(R.string.alert_start_msg);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("calendar_id", 1);
    values.put("title", str);
    values.put("description", m_strDescription);                    
    values.put("dtstart", cal.getTimeInMillis()); 
    values.put("dtend", cal.getTimeInMillis()); 
    values.put("hasAlarm", 1);
    Uri event = cr.insert(EVENTS_URI, values);

    m_calendarEvents[m_calendarEventCount] = event;
    m_calendarEventCount = m_calendarEventCount + 1;

    values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("event_id", Long.parseLong(event.getLastPathSegment()));
    values.put("method", 1);
    values.put("minutes", 10);
    cr.insert(REMINDERS_URI, values);
}
```

}

**class for SDKVersion 14**

```
 public class CycleManagerSDK14 extends CalendarAPI
 {
      public void setAlertOnDevice(Context c)
     {
        long startMillis = 0; 
        long endMillis = 0;     
        Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        beginTime.set(2012, 2, 2, 7, 0);
        startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
        Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        endTime.set(2012, 2, 2, 7, 0);
        endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endMillis);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Walk The Dog");
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "My dog is bored, so we're going on a really long walk!");
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "eventTimezone");
            cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
    }
```

}

Thank you.

Comment: pl. post your error or exception

Comment: class not found exception on CalendarContract

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand, you have 2 problems...

1. You need to access Calender in 2.2 (API 8 and above)
2. From API 14, you need to use CalendarContract to access the Calendar

My suggestion would be Create a abstract class and define the individual implementation.

For example

```
String apiClass;
if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) > Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT) {
    apiClass = "com.example.calendar.version8plus";
} else {
    apiClass = "com.example.calendar.version14plus";
}

try {
    Class<? extends CalendarAPI> realClass = Class.forName(apiClass).asSubclass(CalendarAPI.class);
    api = realClass.newInstance();
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
}
```

With this, you create two different implementation as per the apis...

While compiling depending on your API level exclude the other file from compiling, for this you need to change the API level in Manifest.

Comment: Now in my manifest file i have used this <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" /> so now i change to what

Comment: Hi vinay i have post my code which i have used in my project constructed using api level 8. Can u please show me how your code can be implemented using in my project.

Comment: @RahulBorah, try increasing your API level in Manifest to 14 and see if you get the Class not found error??

Comment: Ok thats fine but if i do so then my app doesn't run in api level 8 and above..only it run on api level 14.

Comment: Ok, here is an example, where in Contacts provider info for different API is implemented, so, you can see it and do the same for calendar..  http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/

Comment: Vinay sorry to say but i m not able to catch anything from there..can u please help me to solve this out with an simple example

Comment: Add two more classes one which is for API 8 to 13 and other for 14 and above.. This class extends the CalendarApi class.. In the main ClendarApi class create a abstract method public abstract boolean setAlertOnDevice(Context c) ;

Comment: Set your Manifest to API14. In your Class which handles, API 8 to 13, paste your code. For Api 14, create a object of CalendarContract. Compile the app...

Comment: there is no need to do anything in ClendarApi class just public abstract class CalendarAPI 
{
 public abstract boolean setAlertOnDevice(Context c) ;
}

Comment: You need to You need to add the code which I have provided above in the answer to a staic method in CalendarApi class

Comment: i have updated the code as u said u please check it whether it ok or not

Comment: 1. Replace Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT with FROYO(check what is the name for 2.2).

Comment: 2. Replace apiClass = "com.example.calendar.version8plus" with Actual class names what you have implemented.

Comment: 3. in SDKVersion 14, you should implement the abstract methods

Comment: I made the changes..check it is ok now..i dont understan ur last point

Comment: 4.  public class CycleManagerSDK14 implements CalendarAPI

Comment: 5. public class CycleManagerSDK8 implements CalendarAPI

Comment: But the calendar api is not an interface? it is an abstract class..how can i implement this

Comment: Create it as an interface. In your main project where you will be calling this try calling the following code: CalendarApi capi = CalendarApi.getAPI(); capi.setAlertOnDevice(getApplicationContext) ;

Comment: If i declared it as interface then i cant implemented method inside it but u said that the code u have provided should be written there..can u please edit my code if u have a time

Comment: Sorry.. Change it to Abstract class. and Extends

Comment: hi vinay i have done as u say..but my question is that u have said change the Manifest to API14. but if i do so then it will not run in API 8 and above.But my app is already publish so if i change it to API 14 then what is use of it.

Comment: Did you try running it on API 8.. It should work.. It is always backward compatable. Secondly, API 8 is loaded from the phone, which has all the features you need.. So, it should work..